# sorting listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview, sorting

i am using this code to sort my list view in alphabetic order but it doesn't sort it a-z it sorts it z-a where is The problem?

```
adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override 
    public int compare(String arg1, String arg0) {
        return -arg1.compareTo(arg0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the character '-' between `return` and `arg1.compareTo(arg0);` ?

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `'-'` between `return` and `arg1.compareTo(arg0);`. That will do the trick for you..

The following will sort in z-a(descending) order.

```
adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override 
    public int compare(String arg1, String arg0) {
        return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
    }
});
```

For, a-z(ascending) :

```
adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override 
        public int compare(String arg1, String arg0) {
            return arg1.compareTo(arg0);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Collections.sort(yourArrayList)` and then reload yourArrayList into the adapter.

here is some code supports my answer

YourAdapter.java

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    protected ArrayList<String> data;
    public void addSomeData()
    {
        data.add("oranj");
        data.add("apple");
        data.add("pineapple");
    }
    public YourAdapter sortData()
    {
        Collections.sort(data);
        return this;
    }
    public int getCount()
    {
        return data.size();
    }

    public String getItem(int position)
    {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
}
```

and in your activity

```
list.setAdapter(new YourAdapter(this)); // not sorted list
list.setAdapter(new YourAdapter(this).sortData()); // sorted list
```

Comment: May you explain your answer a bit? please!