# How to hide a list item?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using a `BaseAdapter` with the view holder pattern.

And I want to hide a certain items from the `Listview` setting :

`convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

does nothing.

Comment: Could you post the whole `getView()` method from your adapter?

Comment: @AndrewSchuster is a straight forward implementation of http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html
 that does work

Comment: `View listItem = convertView;View v;while (!(v = (View) listItem.getParent()).equals(parent)) {
                listItem = v;
            }
listItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);` put i'm not sure if convertView has parent in getView ;/ ... it happend because item that you create in getView could not be the same as added directly to ListView-ViewGroup ... ListView implementation can pack your view in some other view before it add to itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove its item from adapter's list and reload adaper, if you need to show that item again then consider using another list.

This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705004/sorting-listview-in-android/19705061#19705061) do what you need manipulating the list, it sorts, you can adapt it for removing items

**Edit**

To implement undo, you may need a list that holds original values, a stack to hold removed item indices and another list to be generated from original list-removed_indices and that will be used in your adapter

Comment: yea that is my idea as well, removing the items, and then adding them.
but it looks ugly for me since i want the items to be at a specific place in the list(position).

Comment: that solution reloads the list, that's its only effects, but you seem to be uncomfortable with that

Comment: well i will remove the items, call notifydatasethanged and add them again if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
listitem.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

or

```
listitem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: do you know the difference between `View.INVISIBLE` and `View.GONE`?

Comment: he can also write View.GONE i know. but I meant he should set the listitem invisible and not the view.

Comment: when the view is invisible then there will be a 'place holder' for the view.

Comment: he is already using `convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` .... are you writing the answers just for writing?

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```
ListActivity.this.setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactsList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_CONTACT_NAME, TAG_STATUS}, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.status}){

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


                TextView statTview = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.status);
                            String stat = statTview .getText().toString();

                if (stat.equals("0")){
                    v.findViewById(R.id.status).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }


        return v;
    }

}
);
```

Comment: seems like he is already doing this(we can assume this from question ... did you read it?) ... so this is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can store the hidden positions in another ArrayList and hide that item like this :

```
public class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayList<Integer> hiddenPositions = new ArrayList<>();

    public SampleAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listItems) {
        this.activity = activtity;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // The following small snippet of code ensures 
        // that we skip data from all the hidden positions 
        // and use the updated position to fetch the 
        // correct data from the listItems ArrayList. 
        for(Integer hiddenIndex : hiddenPositions) {
            if(hiddenIndex <= position) {
                position = position + 1;
            }
        }
        String testString = listItems.get(position);
        ...
    }    

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItems.size() - hiddenPositions.size();
    }
}
```

To be able to show it back in the list, just remove the position from the `hiddenPositions` ArrayList and do a `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Explained it better here : http://vshivam.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/hiding-a-list-item-from-an-android-listview-without-removing-it-from-the-data-source/