# android- change sort of listivew

Tags: android, android-listview

i want change the order of listview to be the recent items added be in the top of listview , old be last down

i get the data from sqlite , then fill them to arraylist of objects called reports_items_obj
i use custom adpater to view

```
  ListView list_messages = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

     Report_adapter adapter = new  Report_adapter(getApplicationContext(), reports_items_obj);
     list_messages.setAdapter(adapter);

 xml file 


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

         <ListView
              android:id="@+id/list"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent">
         </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187504/how-to-sort-listview-items-in-descending-order

Comment: and here: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705004/sorting-listview-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which listview is based on the order of items in arraylist or cursor or from whereever the data is stored which will be populated in the listview. So try changing the order of arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

Solution lies in the data source. Lets say you are getting the data from a sqlite db, when you are querying the db use `order by desc` on a column.

You need to specify the data source to give a complete answer.